# Copying a range of cells from a closed workbook to outlook email already containing a body using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying to copy a range of cells onto the body of an outlook email that already has some text. My current code is as follows but it keeps crashing:

```
Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim outContent As Object
Dim copiedRange As Range

Set sourceWorkbook = Workbook.Open("file location")
Set outEmail = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")
Set outContent = objOut.CreateItem(0)

Set copiedRange = Sheet("sheet name").RangeToHtml("A1:D5")
copiedRange.Select
With Selection
    .Copy
End With 

With outContent 
    .Body = "blah blah blah"
    .HTMLBody = RangeToHtml.copiedRange      
End With
```

Comment: *Exactly how* does it crash? `Workbook.Open("file location")` should be `Workbooks.Open("file location")`

Comment: Hi Tim - I keep getting Sub or Function not defined

Comment: With my suggested code, or your original code?  If you're commenting on my suggestions then you can comment below the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim outContent As Object
Dim copiedRange As Range

Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("file location")
Set outEmail = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")
Set outContent = outEmail.CreateItem(0)

Set copiedRange = sourceWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name").Range("A1:D5")

With outContent 
    .Body = "blah blah blah"
    .HTMLBody = RangeToHtml(copiedRange)      
End With
```